# How did people in pre-Ampere period deduce this?

Tags: physics, electromagnetism, magnetism

How did *people before Ampere (eg-Coulomb)* who used *magnetic-pole model*, know that only two surfaces (north and south poles) of a bar magnet exerts and experiences force while the rest of the surfaces is free from magnetic force? Is there a deduction for this or is it just a guess made from experiment with two bar magnets?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean with "the rest of the surfaces is free from magnetic force". Also why do you think this statement was a fact before Ampère and Coulomb?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who determined whether surfaces between magnetic poles attract/repel or whether the poles' volumes do?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/7676/who-determined-whether-surfaces-between-magnetic-poles-attract-repel-or-whether) Please search for existing questions before posting here, there was a question about this just a single scroll down the list.